# How to not include URL query string in HTTP Referrer

Tags: http, redirect, browser, referrer, referrer-policy

What is the best way to ensure that a query string does not get included as part of HTTP Referrer data?

I have noticed that some potentially sensitive information (*e.g.* UTM fields, which do not really require SSL) may otherwise leak.

The objective is for an originating URL such as:

```
http://mywebsite.com/mypage/?myvar=xxx
```

To be passed as referrer only as:

```
http://mywebsite.com/mypage/
```

I have read about the [referrer policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-no-referrer) meta directive (
`<meta name="referrer" content="origin">`), but [it doesn't seem to be widely implemented](http://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy).

Comment: I take it you are not in full control over which clients are accessing your site?

Comment: Yes. I know that at the end the browser has full authority on this, but I am looking for a well supported solution (if any exists).

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should use the `noreferrer` directive, either in separate links (`<a rel="noreferrer">`) or as you say set a referrer policy.

But there are other solutions, i.e., hacks: like this one:

> Another referrer hiding method is to convert the original link URL to a Data URI scheme-based URL containing small HTML page with a meta refresh to the original URL. When the user is redirected from the data: page, the original referrer is hidden. The first public implementation of this method is the Darefer app for ownCloud

That is a quote from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#Referer_hiding

PS. This is all for completely hide the referrer header and not only removing the query string.